# Trigger to populate a table when row is inserted in another table

Tags: oracle, triggers

i wish to create a trigger which inserts 7 records in child table after i enter one record in parent table.
The child must contain primary key of the parent table.

i have tried this

```
CREATE TRIGGER journey_date_append
AFTER  INSERT 
ON BUS_DETAILS 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE   
BEGIN 
   insert into BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS values (BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS_SEQ.nextval, new.BUS_DETAILS_PK,sysdate, 'subham',sysdate, 'subham', 'NORMAL')
END;/
```

it got saved but with some errors and when i ran it ,

```
Row 15: ORA-04098: trigger 'FRS2014_OVMGMT.ADD_JOURNEY_DATE' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

The insert statement is correct , i have checked it separately.

Comment: suppose my parent table is "parent" and child table is "child"

Comment: OK. Nothing stopping you doing that. What is your question? You haven't shown your table structures or given any indication of what data should be used for the child table, apart from the foreign key. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: @AlexPoole how to create it ?

Comment: You can do `show errors` or `select * from user_errors` to see the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question this is the final trigger which adds 7 records in child table
(BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS) when a record is inserted in parent (BUS_DETAILS)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER journey_date_append
    AFTER  INSERT 
    ON BUS_DETAILS 
    FOR EACH ROW   
    BEGIN 
       insert into BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS values (BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS_SEQ.nextval, :new.BUS_DETAILS_PK,sysdate, 'subham',sysdate, 'subham',sysdate, 'NORMAL');
       insert into BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS values (BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS_SEQ.nextval, :new.BUS_DETAILS_PK,sysdate+1, 'subham',sysdate, 'subham',sysdate, 'NORMAL'); 
       insert into BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS values (BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS_SEQ.nextval, :new.BUS_DETAILS_PK,sysdate+2, 'subham',sysdate, 'subham',sysdate, 'NORMAL');
       insert into BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS values (BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS_SEQ.nextval, :new.BUS_DETAILS_PK,sysdate+3, 'subham',sysdate, 'subham',sysdate, 'NORMAL');
       insert into BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS values (BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS_SEQ.nextval, :new.BUS_DETAILS_PK,sysdate+4, 'subham',sysdate, 'subham',sysdate, 'NORMAL');
       insert into BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS values (BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS_SEQ.nextval, :new.BUS_DETAILS_PK,sysdate+5, 'subham',sysdate, 'subham',sysdate, 'NORMAL');
       insert into BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS values (BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS_SEQ.nextval, :new.BUS_DETAILS_PK,sysdate+6, 'subham',sysdate, 'subham',sysdate, 'NORMAL');
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've only shown one child record being inserted, and you need to do `show errors` or `select * from user_errors` to see the actual problem. One obvious problem is that you haven't prefixed your `new` [pseudorecord](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955) value with a colon - it shoudl be `:new.BUS_DETAILS_PK`. And you aren't declaring any variables so you don't need the `DECLARE` keyword:

```
CREATE TRIGGER journey_date_append
AFTER  INSERT 
ON BUS_DETAILS 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
   insert into BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS values (BUS_JOURNEY_DETAILS_SEQ.nextval,
      :new.BUS_DETAILS_PK,sysdate, 'subham',sysdate, 'subham', 'NORMAL')
END;
/
```

It is better to list the target tables columns so you can be sure the values are aligned properly, and to give some protection against future schema changes. Only you know if the other values you're passing are valid and in the right order for your current table.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace trigger PARENT_TRG_AI_R
after insert on PARENT
for each row
begin
  insert into child (column1,column2,...,PARENT_ID) values (value1,value2,...,:new.PARENT_ID);
  insert into child (column1,column2,...,PARENT_ID) values (value1,value2,...,:new.PARENT_ID);
  insert into child (column1,column2,...,PARENT_ID) values (value1,value2,...,:new.PARENT_ID);
  insert into child (column1,column2,...,PARENT_ID) values (value1,value2,...,:new.PARENT_ID);
  insert into child (column1,column2,...,PARENT_ID) values (value1,value2,...,:new.PARENT_ID);
  insert into child (column1,column2,...,PARENT_ID) values (value1,value2,...,:new.PARENT_ID);
  insert into child (column1,column2,...,PARENT_ID) values (value1,value2,...,:new.PARENT_ID);
end;
```

You can call the trigger anything you like - this is just my suggestion.